# Android: Substring & IF

Tags: java, android, if-statement, substring

I have a problem with the following code. I cut the String "Data1", give it to "Data2" and then I check the String. My Phone always says "ab is not ab", but I do not know why? -.-

Any ideas?

```
String Data1 = "abc";
String Data2 = "";

Data2 = Data1.substring(0, 2);

if(Data2 == "ab")
  {
        Toast.makeText(this, Data2 + " is ab" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
else
  {
        Toast.makeText(this, Data2 + " is not ab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  }
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

In Java you compare strings using the method `equals()`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Change your `if` statement as follows

```
if(Data2.equals("ab"))
{
    Toast.makeText(this, Data2 + " is ab" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(this, Data2 + " is not ab", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```